# Как изменить style , всех объектов внутри div

Tags: javascript, html

у меня есть HTML код

```html
<div id="area" class="wrapper">
  <div class="vopros" id="vopros">
    <div class="top_strip" id="top_strip">
      <div class="meter">
        <span id="number"><span><p id="numbq"></p></span></span>
      </div>
      <p id="time">00:00</p>
    </div>
    <div class="picture">
      <img src="img/1.png" id="picture" class="picture">
    </div>
    <p id="question"></p>
    <div class="line-question" id="line-question" onclick="vari(0)">
      <img src="img/button-2.svg" id="pict-1" class="pict" height="20px">
      <a class="myButton" id="option1"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="line-question" id="line-question" onclick="vari(1)">
      <img src="img/button-2.svg" id="pict-2" class="pict" height="20px">
      <a class="myButton" id="option2"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="line-question" id="line-question" onclick="vari(2)">
      <img src="img/button-2.svg" id="pict-3" class="pict" height="20px">
      <a class="myButton" id="option3"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="line-question" id="line-question-4" onclick="vari(3)">
      <img src="img/button-2.svg" id="pict-4" class="pict" height="20px" id="option4">
      <a class="myButton" id="option4"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="bot-button" id="bot-button">
      <a onclick="vari(4)" id="option7" class="option7">Далее</a>
      <a onclick="vari(8)" id="option8" class="option8">Назад</a>
      <a onclick="vari(9)" id="option9" class="option9">Завершить</a>
    </div>
```

в нем всем объектам присвоено `display:none;`, как можно изменить его на `display:block;` всем элементам внутри `<div id="area" class="wrapper">`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function showAll() {
  document.querySelectorAll("#area *").forEach(
    e => e.style.display = "block"
  );
}
```

```css
#area * {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showAll()">Show All</button>
<div id="area">
<div>Test DIV<span>Test SPAN inside DIV</span></div>
<span>Test SPAN</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Не надо прописывать `display:none` всем элементам в `div`, пропишите это свойство самому `div`.